# Base de datos Multi inquilinos laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

si me pudieran ayudar, estoy trabajando en laravel 5.8 y dentro de mi proyecto quiero crear dos conexiones una para login (ya creada) la segunda que no sea una conexion estatica osea que dependa de los datos del login por parte del cliente para conectar a una base de datos especifica

para una base de datos estatica no tengo problemas pero tendre cientos de bases de datos que la idea es que conecte a su respectiva base de datos segun la sesion iniciada

archivo database.php

```
    'base_datos_login' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

   'base_datos_cliente' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',

            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,

        ],
```

archivo .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=base_datos_login
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bd_login
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''

DB_CONNECTION=base_datos_cliente
DB_HOST_2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_2=3306
DB_DATABASE_2=bd_cliente
DB_USERNAME_2=root
DB_PASSWORD_2=''
```

Modelo eloquent

```
    class Mimodelo extends Model
    {
    protected $connection = 'base_datos_cliente';
    }
```

adjunto imagen explicativa
gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías explicarnos cuál el la razón para hacer eso?? Cientos de bases de datos?  Entonces son bases de datos existentes y te conectas o tambien las vas creando? Faltan muchos detalles a la pregunta, intenta explicar mejor todos los requerimientos y especificaciones.

Comment: adjunté imagen explicativa, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Por ejemplo tuve una situacion similar con un sistema de facturación e inventario para pequeños y medianos negocios y se ameritaba trabajar con muchas bases de datos, dicho sistema tiene el mismo enfoque planteado por davideliecer donde parto de una base de datos comun donde se guarda la autenticacion de usuario y los datos principales que en comun tienen todos los negocios: clientes, productos, empresas, cotizacion moneda, entre otros, y por otro lado, luego de autenticado el usuario se abre la base de datos con sus datos: ventas, compras, inventario.

Originalmente trabajaba con una base de datos y para cada negocio abria un esquema diferente pero trabajar asi era complicado a la hora de hacer respaldo porque implicaba cerrar el servicio del sistema para realizar labores de mantenimiento, pero lo más significativo era que al hacer el respaldo demoraba tiempos prohibitivos debido a que el tamaño de la base de datos era considerablemente enorme.

**davideliecer:** Estas bien encaminado y sabes cual es el punto de partida, vamos a darte el empujon para que puedas aplicar el escenario que estas desarrollando, lo que vamos a hacer es establecer la conexión en forma dinámica:

**Paso 1.** Crear un helpers para adicionar un metodo el cual retorne el nombre de la conexión que deseamos obtener. Supongamos que tenemos dos bases de datos, una en MySQL y la otra en SQL Server, en app/helpers.php agregamos dos funciones que devolveran los nombres de las conexiones.

```
<?php
    function getConexionMysql(){
        return "DB_MYSQL";
    }

        function getConexionSqlsrv(){
        return "DB_SQLSRV";
    }
?>
```

**Paso 2.** Adicionar el helper en el archivo composer.json, en la sección autoload. Agregar el archivo app/helpers.php en composer.json para que sea tomado en forma global.

```
 "autoload": {
     "classmap": [
         "database"
     ],
     "psr-4": {
         "ApiRest\\": "app/"
     },
     "files": [
         "app/helpers.php"
     ]
 },
```

**Paso 3.** Ejecutar en la consola el siguiente comando, para así cargar el archivo de manera global.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**Paso 4.** En el archivo database.php de la carpeta config, agregamos una nueva conexión que contenga los parametros de conexión. En este caso crearemos dos conexiones; una en mysql y otra a sqlsrv. De está manera podremos generar el punto de conexión a diferentes bases de datos.

```
'DB_MYSQL' => [
    'driver'      => 'mysql',
    'host'        => env('DB_HOST_MYSQL', 'forge'),
    'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE_MYSQL', 'forge'),
    'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME_MYSQL', 'forge'),
    'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD_MYSQL', ''),
    'prefix'      => '',
],

'DB_SQLSRV' => [
    'driver'      => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'        => env('DB_HOST_SQLSRV', 'forge'),
    'database'    => env('DB_DATABASE_SQLSRV', 'forge'),
    'username'    => env('DB_USERNAME_SQLSRV', 'forge'),
    'password'    => env('DB_PASSWORD_SQLSRV', ''),
    'prefix'      => '',
],
```

**Paso 5.** Ahora en el archivo .env agregamos los parametros de conexión correspondientes y, así los métodos anteriores lograrán realizar las conexiones pertinentes.

```
DB_CONNECTION_MYSQL=DB_MYSQL
DB_HOST_MYSQL=XXX
DB_DATABASE_MYSQL=XXX
DB_USERNAME_MYSQL=XXX
DB_PASSWORD_MYSQL=XXX

DB_CONNECTION_SQLSRV=DB_SQLSRV
DB_HOST_SQLSRV=XXX
DB_DATABASE_SQLSRV=XXX
DB_USERNAME_SQLSRV=XXX
DB_PASSWORD_SQLSRV=XXX
```

**Paso 6.** En el modelo que se vaya a consultar los datos le pasamos el método del helper, para que llame la conexión que desea realizar. De está manera podremos acceder a multiples bases de datos y no necesariamente a la conexión por defecto.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contacto extends Model
{
    protected $table = "contacto";
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('fecha', 'tipo', 'nombre', 'telefono', 'email', );

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = getConexionMysql();
    }
}
```

Finalmente **davideliecer** puedes parametrizar el helper para adaptarlo a tus necesidades, por ejemplo luego de autenticado el usuario buscar en una tabla donde tengas grabadas todas las conexiones (1 por cada inquilino) y que se capture el respectivo valor que corresponda con el usuario logueado. Ahora bien, donde vas a hacer mantenimiento es en agregar nuevas conexiones tanto en la tabla de conexiones, como también en config/database.php y en .env, obviamente tendrias que crear una base de datos por cada nueva conexión. De esta forma el numero de bases de datos que podría usar el sistema sería ilimitado, pudiendo utilizar diversas fuentes de almacenamiento como bases de datos locales, VPNs, hostings externos dedicados, etc.

La gran ventaja de trabajar asi es que ahora solo tendrías que hacer respaldos sobre bases de datos especificas sin afectar la conexión de las demás, la otra ventaja es que los respaldos consistirían en archivos más pequeños y por consiguiente el tiempo de mantemiento es mas reducido lo que redunda en pocos tiempos de fuera de servicio del sistema.

Esperando que esta información te sirva de algo.

Answer (score 0):

Me auto respondo por si alguien lo necesita, sistema multi inquilinos

```
archivo database.php

    //conexion login 
    'base_datos_login' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,
            ],
    //conexion base datos clients
       'base_datos_cliente' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',

                'prefix' => '',
                'strict' => true,
                'engine' => null,

            ],
archivo .env

DB_CONNECTION=base_datos_login
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bd_login
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''

DB_CONNECTION=base_datos_cliente
DB_HOST_2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_2=3306
DB_DATABASE_2=''
DB_USERNAME_2=root
DB_PASSWORD_2=''


archivo AuthenticatesUsers.php

//creo la session_base_datos para conectar
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
    session(['session_base_datos' => Auth::user()->base_datos]);
}

//en el controlador creo __construct()
//usar config y DB
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //base de datos



 class Controller extends Controller
    {

    public function __construct()
      {
    //sessiones dentro de construct
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    //variable sesion
    $this->base_datos = session()->get('session_base_datos');
    //nueva conexion
    Config::set('database.connections.base_datos_cliente.database',$this->base_datos);
    Config::set('database.default', 'base_datos_cliente');
    DB::reconnect();DB::purge('mysql');
    return $next($request);

     });
      }
    }
```

nueva conexion ejecutada en el controlador

ahora si se puede mejorar, se agradeceria

Comment: hola, como puedo saber si se realizo la conexion?? por ejemplo si la conexion de base_datos_cliente se encuentra en otro servidor y este esta apagado; como puedo saber si la conexion se realizo o no?